# How to insert into a table1 column where another table1 column is the same as table2 column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I am trying to insert the product types into a my table called `ro_frames` which can be accessed from table `ro_st_product` where the `ro_frames.product_id  = ro_st_product.product_id` .

For this I use the following query:

```
insert into ro_frames(product_type)
(SELECT a.producttype
   FROM ro_st_product a join  ro_frames b on a.product_id = b.product_id
   where a.product_id = b.PRODUCT_ID);
```

It says that:

> Action:
> 1,405 rows inserted.

However when I go to `ro_frames` the values inside the column `product_type` is all null. Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting new *rows*.  I think you want `update`:

```
update ro_frames f
    set product_type = (select a.producttype
                        from ro_st_product p 
                        where p.product_id = f.PRODUCT_ID
                       );
```

That said, you shouldn't be storing the same value in two places.  You should just use `join` when you are querying to get the type from the product table.